# App WebAssembly Blazor + Swagger + Hangfire broken routes

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, hangfire

I'm fairly new to this stack. I've started with visual studio 2022 "App WebAssembly Blazor".
A simple db/api with a scheduled job. Everything in debug work as expected, but when deployed in production neither swagger UI nor Hangfire Dashboard comes up until a do a ctrl+f5 (and for every single page after, every time i click in a link from swagger/hangfire, blazor template redirect me on wrong address page, but after a ctrl+f5 i'm on correct page) this beavihour does not appear in visual studio, but appear in both if i launch app by command line or if i launch in iis server.

```
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Wrong Address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
```

In client application it seems that does not find this context.
In server application i tried everything maked sense to me:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "my api", Version = "v1" });
});
```

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
    Authorization = new[] { new DashboardUiFilter() }
});
```

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapHangfireDashboard();
app.MapSwagger();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

What i'm missing? I've got no more clues.

Comment: It's difficult to find the error based on your description, Have you checked that the link is different before and after when you do ctrl+f5?

Comment: I changed from webassembly to webapplication and everything work as expected!